# unable to create magento categories 1.8.1.0 - JS error 'Tree is undefined'

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have installed version 1.8.1.0. It's a clean install not an upgrade.

When I go to Manage Categories I cannot add a Root category or a Sub-Category. It doesn't save nothing happens. when I inspect element and go into Console there are 2 errors - the first one that pops up is

```
TypeError: tree is undefined
if (!tree.currentNodeId) {
```

the other error is

```
TypeError: Ext.tree.CheckNodeMultiSelectionModel is not a constructor
selModel        : new Ext.tree.CheckNodeMultiSelectionModel(),
```

I can create products fine, the only thing I should mention but shouldn't affect the category page is that I have someone doing me a new theme for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if /js/extjs/ext-tree.js and /js/extjs/ext-tree-checkbox.js are loaded on category page.